# Did Rav Shach allow people to move to the Occupied Territories?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, rav-shach

Did Rav Elazar Menachem Man Shach forbid people from moving into the Occupied Territories after they were captured in 1967? If yes, what was his reason for forbidding it?

Comment: Why would you think he did? This is a really random question. Try [edit]ing to explain why you ask this and not "Did Mr. Ploni Almoni forbid people from moving into the Occupied Territories after they were captured in 1967? If yes, what was his reason for forbidding it?"

Comment: Also consider a less-politicized/divisive way to refer to the land in question.

Answer (score 0):

HaRav Shach in Michtavim U'Maamarim 2:4 strongly wrote against settling in the territories.

See [truetorahjews.org](http://www.truetorahjews.org/qanda/settlers)

> Rabbi Elazar M. Shach ztl wrote about the settlers in his sefer
>   Mictavim Umaamarim 2:4: The idea of settling is simply starting up
>   with the nations of the world, and it comes from the fundamental error
>   of the Zionists, who think that all that has ever befallen us is
>   because we did not have a state and Jewish sovereignty, but now that
>   we are a state equal with all the states of the world, if we show
>   strength and do not budge, our enemies will back away. Even if there
>   are many who adhere to these views, it is a departure from the path we
>   have received from Chazal, and the opposite is the truth.
>
> The opposite that showing strength and not budging will only lead to
>   further attacks and further loss of life is the truth, according to
>   Rav Shach.